# Typescript refactoring

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, refactoring

This code works correct . But it looks weird for me . Especially this part ```
const city = [].concat(...locationCities).includes('London');
if(city === true)

apiClient:

```
export interface apiRequest {
  locations: LocationOptions[];

}
interface FOLocations {
  locationId: number;
}

interface LocationResult {
  location: FOLocations[];
  address: Address;
}
interface LocationResult {
country:string;
city:string;
}
export const locationCheck = async (
  apiKey: string,
  payload: apiRequest
): Promise<LocationResult[]> => {
  let response = await axios.post<LocationResult[]>(
    `api...`,
    payload
  );
  return response.data;
```

runCode:

```
  const locationPayload : apiRequest = {
      locations:[{ cityName: "London"},{cityName: "New York"},{cityName: "Paris"}],
    };
    const locationResponse = await locationCheck(apiKey,locationPayload);
    const locationCities = locationResponse.map((location) => location.address.map(options => {return options.country}));
    console.log(locationCities);
    const city = [].concat(...locationCities).includes('London');
    console.log(city);
```

```
  if(city === true){
      console.log(`London location exist`);
    }else {
      throw new Error(
            "error"
      );
    }
```

Output :

```
true
London location exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can delete this line:

```
const city = [].concat(...locationCities).includes('London');
```

And replace this:

```
if(city === true){
  // ...
```

With this:

```
if(locationCities.includes('London')){
  // ...
```